# detecting a redirect with javascript - how?

Tags: javascript, redirect, detection

Is there any way to detect whether a webpage is going to redirect me to another, knowing its URL? I mean the situation when you type URL in a text field and the script examines it for 3xx redirections.

Comment: There is an event `onbeforeunload`, is that what you want?

Comment: @fardjad Maybe I didn't explain it correctly. I need something like [this](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/), but with javascript, not php

Comment: If it meets the same origin policy you should probably be able to get the 302 header via the XHR object.

Comment: Maybe you could use a iframe... Load that url in a iframe and compare its location. Although you might need to work around the cross-domain issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this quite easily in Javascript.  It'd look something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status < 400 && this.status >= 300) {
    alert('this redirects to ' + this.getResponseHeader("Location"));
  } else {
    alert('doesn\'t redirect ');
  }
}
xhr.open('HEAD', '/my/location', true);
xhr.send();
```

Unfortunately, this only works on your own server, unless you hit a server with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) set up.  If you wanted to work uniformly across any domain, you're going to have to do it server-side.

Comment: I might be wrong here but I think this might not work and the only method to check that you were redirected or not is to inspect **responseURL** attribute
https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responseurl-attribute
If it is different then the URL used in **open** method there was a redirect

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple solution for your question.

```
x.addEventListener('readystatechange',function(){

    const url = 'https://your/request/url';
    if(this.responseURL != url){
        alert('redirected');
    }

});
```

Comment: And what is `x` here?