# Javascript detect URL the user is leaving to

Tags: javascript

My website, as most websites today, uses the same template for most of its pages and I am building a system that allows for ajax to load only page content without reloading the whole template. For the purpose I'm looking for a method that fires before the browser is redirected to another page. Something like `onbeforeunload` but I also need to know the location of the redirect, is there such a thing?

I need to catch link clicks, back button clicks, forward button clicks as well as manual redirects like `window.location = url`

Comment: `window.onunload = yourfuction;`

Comment: @Kiee but how do I know where the user is going?

Comment: If your using ajax to generate the page content, the page wont be reloaded?

Comment: @Kiee yes but how do I know which page to load? This function only detects when the user is leaving, not where he's going

Comment: Already been answered?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930927/how-can-i-detect-an-address-bar-change-with-javascript

Comment: @Kiee this is unacceptable and unreliable

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638591/detecting-a-redirect-with-javascript-how

Comment: @sunny yes I found this as well but I don't see how it can apply in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to find out what URL the user is leaving the page for.

You would need to bind event handlers to the various different things that the user can use to leave the current page.

For links, you can bind a `click` event handler and then examine the `href` attribute.

For forms, you can bind a `submit` event handler and then collect the form data and examine the `action` and `method`.

For the back button you can bind a `popstate` event handler (which you could use in conjunction with `pushState` and friends).

You, obviously, couldn't detect where the user was going if they used a bookmark or just typed a new address into the address bar.